# Accessing the Drop down list selection as a variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropdownbox

I have drop down list in my view(created using Select tag)
How can use the user selection in my rails code (for example pass it to a method)
to be clear:

(this is about getting pages that are owned by a certain facebook user)

```
<select name="user_pages" >
<% @accounts.each do |account|%>
    <option value="<%=account['id']%>"><%=account['name']%> </option>
<%end%>     
</select>
```

and i have a share button that depending on user choice calls a method

```
    <a href=" <%=share_on_page_path(:id=>@querk.id,:index=>@selected) %>" >
 <img alt="" src=<%="/images/fshare.png"%> /></a>
```

How can i assing the result of selection to @selected? or anything else that have the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, print out the contents of the `params` hash. That would give you an indication of all the values that were passed from the form.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It doesn't get passed to the function by default which is fine, what i want to know is how i can read the selected value once user clicks on the button.I want to pass the selected value to my rails action manually. Do i need to use unobtrusive javascript. if so, how?

Comment: To pass the variables, you would need to wrap the above code snippet in a form. This might give you some idea: http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form.